# Loading Flat file with fixed width and three different row types into SQL Server as xml data type with SSIS 2012

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

I am new to SQL Server and SSIS and have this scenario.  I have this coded and working in TSQL and have been trying to figure out if I can do it in SSIS as I would like to use some of the error handling it offers. I am currently running this in SQL 2008, but I am testing SSIS using 2012. Here is my scenario.

FIXED WIDTH FLAT FILE FORMAT:
HEADER CODE FILE_TYPE DATE
CODE LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME GENDER
 
TRAILER CODE DATE RECORD_COUNT

FLAT FILE CONTENTS:

```
H0123ABC07222013
98765SMITH   TOM     M
94586JOHNSON BILL    M
T0123072220132
```

In TSQL my steps are
BULK INSERT into large temp table and load as one column
Building a query string of:
Select values using SUBSTRING using FOR XML and using a where clause for Header value
,
Select values using SUBSTRING using FOR XML and using a where clause for DETAILS value
,
Select values using SUBSTRING using FOR XML and using a where clause for TRAILER value

For Example:

```
SELECT @sql1 =  (SELECT 
    ( SELECT SUBSTRING(temp,1,2) as Header,
             SUBSTRING(temp,3,3) as CODE ,
             SUBSTRING(temp,6,3) as File_Type,
             SUBSTRING(temp,9,8) as Cycle_Date
        FROM TestLoad
       WHERE SUBSTRING(temp,1,2) = 'H0'
    FOR
    XML PATH('HEADER'),
    TYPE
    ), ...
```

The result of that query is inserted into an XML data type column

I have found information on how to do this in SSIS writing to a table that is structured to match the data but have not found how to convert the data to XML and keep the order of the file intact.  XML conversion is where I am struggling.

Thanks

Comment: I am beginning to think either I labeled this question wrong or converting flat files to xml is not a job for SSIS.

Comment: I have implemented this in a round about way, using an TSQL task in SSIS to convert the data to XML and than insert it.  However that was not really my goal, i wanted to use SSIS to do it somehow.  My solution does the work but does not allow for good error handling and such, for instance, making sure the values are compliant with the XSD and handling those errors accordingly.  If SSIS cannot do it, can anyone make a suggestion of another tool that can.

Comment: I am now taking steps to do the XML conversion outside of MS.  I am looking at using ServingXML project from source forge.  I will program all the conversions out there, than import the resulting XML file to the database.